Reusing a expensive view in SwiftUI
I have a expensive GIF animated view that I use as a activity indicator and it needs to be used in a lot of places in the UI, wherever the user encounters a API call.
In the UIKit world, I would warm up a UIView with the animated gif, and create a new UIWindow, keep a reference to it and add it as a root view and make the window visible and hidden when required. Easy.
However I have a hard time figuring out how I could achieve the same in SwiftUI. Or maybe I'm going about this all wrong. Help appreciated!
Not that it'd help, but what I had in mind for the loading indicator, which I would call via .modifier(LoadingIndicator(...)) wherever required.
struct LoadingIndicator<ProgressViewType: View>: ViewModifier {
    var isShowing: Bool
    @ViewBuilder
    var progressView: () -> ProgressViewType
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            if isShowing {
                loadingView
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var loadingView: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxyReader in
            ZStack {
                Color.white.opacity(0.1)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                progressView()
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        //.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)))
    }
}

Edit:
Ok, this is what I have so far. To clarify the expensive bit, the loading indicator that is being used is a GIF. I ran and profiled my app a couple of times and the memory usage shoots up.
Every time I profiled when the loading indicator is displayed, the CPU usage reads 20% for a moment, while hovering around 2% otherwise. I'm no a expert, but doesn't frequently allocating and deallocating drain battery life?
If this is a non-issue, I am happy to leave it as is, since this works as expected.
I have trimmed down and added a reproducible example:
This requires the SDWebImageSwiftUI package. And any 10MB GIF.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> some View) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

struct LoadingIndicator<ProgressViewType: View>: ViewModifier {
    var isShowing: Bool
    @ViewBuilder
    var progressView: () -> ProgressViewType
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            if isShowing {
                loadingView
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var loadingView: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxyReader in
            ZStack {
                Color.white.opacity(0.1)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                progressView()
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)))
    }
    
    fileprivate static var defaultProgressView: some View {
        ProgressView()
            .progressViewStyle(
                CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .white)
            )
            .scaleEffect(x: 2, y: 2, anchor: .center)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func loadingIndicator<ProgressView: View>(_ isShowing: Bool, @ViewBuilder progressView: @escaping () -> ProgressView) -> some View {
        
        self.if(isShowing) { $0.blur(radius: 10) }
            .modifier(LoadingIndicator(isShowing: isShowing, progressView: progressView))
    }
    
    func tpActivityIndicator(_ isShowing: Bool) -> some View {
        
        loadingIndicator(isShowing) {
            VStack {
                AnimatedImage(name: "loading_indicator.gif")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 130, height: 150)
                Text("Loading...")
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    VStack {
        Text("Lorem Ipsum")
    }
    .padding()
    .background { Color.yellow }
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
    .tpActivityIndicator(true)
}


SwiftUI views are not reusable. They are created as needed.

In what way is the view “expensive”? Can you show a [mre] demonstrating that your loading indicator would be expensive?

@Sweeper
The loading indicator is a GIF. I'm using SDWebImage to render it in a AnimatedImage, and when loaded it consumes about 20MB of memory, which I assume is expensive?

If it's memory, how would "keep a reference to it and add it as a root view and make the window visible and hidden when required" help? If it's the loading that is time-consuming, I can understand that. In any case though, without seeing a [mre], it's not enough for me to give an answer.

@Sweeper I have put together bits of code and added a reproducible example and added a few more details. Hope that helps. Thanks for your help

View is a value like an int, very cheap when coded correctly. progressView() is expensive though, try to remove that or move it to init. Try to remove your if modifier too that breaks identity.

Ah so AnimatedImage is a View from SDWebImage? You can't really do much about it if you don't have control over the view. You could create your own View that does whatever AnimatedImage does, but gets the image from some central location that is lazily initialised, instead of loading a new image into memory every time it's shown.

Coming from UIKit with reference-based views, the value-based system of SwiftUI can be a little unfamiliar at first.
The most important thing to understand compared to UIKit is that in SwiftUI views should be as lightweight as possible and they are (as mentioned) value types. This also indirectly answers your question about how to make views “reusable” in SwiftUI. The way you use the term, the answer would be “not at all”, because value types are copied and not referenced for reuse.
SwiftUI works in such a way that views are constantly recreated and only their state is transferred to a new instance if required.
I.e. the creation of a SwiftUI view should never be sth. expensive. In principle, the same applies to the layout process of SwiftUI views.
Your actual problem is that you want to optimize the use of an expensive resource that could affect the performance of your app or device.
In your case, according to your description, this is a very large local image (10MB GIF) that needs to be loaded into memory, decompressed and rendered.
As is often the case with this type of problem, you have to choose between different strategies. You can try to load these resources into memory in advance (maybe even in a decompressed state), but this will increase the memory footprint of your app.
Or you can load the resource only when needed, in which case the short-term CPU load increases which may affect your UI.
You have to decide for yourself which strategy is best for your app, as this depends heavily on your specific app and use case.
The tools Instruments provides help you to identify bottlenecks. There are many WWDC videos and blog posts on the web regarding this topic.
For images, you could typically load their data into memory in advance if the image needs to be constantly loaded and displayed in a lot of areas in the app. But then you should always make sure that bitmap-based images do not have to be transformed for display.
You should also ask yourself whether it absolutely has to be a 10MB GIF or whether you can use another more suitable method for the animation display.
For example, by using something like Lottie or another vector-based approach.
If you absolutely want to rely on SDWebImage, you need to take a look at what is offered in the framework in terms of pre-loading or options for retrieving images from a cache.
I.e. SDImageCache could be what you're looking for.
